# Geocoding inside of a coroutine which is inside of an observer isn't running

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, geocoding, kotlin-coroutines

In my fragment i have a `bindUI()` method which contains some liveData that i am observing and inside of the lambda i want to use the value `location` (which contains a latitude and longitude value) to retrieve a list of Addresses based on the coordinates it contains. I was told that Geocoding should be done inside of a coroutine so i'm trying to do that but the code inside the `launch` coroutine doesn't seem to be running. I've placed log statements but they don't run and no result seems to be printed on my textView. The debugger also says that there is no runnable code when i place a breakpoint on it. What am i messing up here?

```
private fun bindUI() = launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
        // fetch the location
        val weatherLocation = viewModel.weatherLocation.await()

        // Observe the location for changes
        weatherLocation.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { location ->
            if (location == null) return@Observer
            //TODO:sp update the location text view
            launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                val task = updateLocation(location)
                locationTxtView.text = task[0].countryName
            }
        })
    }
```

And here's the `updateLocation()` fun:

```
private suspend fun updateLocation(location: WeatherLocation): MutableList<Address> {
    return async(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val geocoder = Geocoder(activity, Locale.getDefault())
        val addr = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.latitude, location.longitude, 10)
        return@async addr
    }.await()
}
```